# Perform Union if table with these names exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have attendance database where every month new table get generated 
like `TRNS0419,TRNS0519,TRNS0619,TRNS0719`.To combine data i have used Union.
But every month i have enter table name manually, Is there any way if automaticalls picks data when ever new table gets generated such TRNS0819

I have tried using union all but its isnt taking table which is not present.

```
Select * from TRNS0419 union all Select * from TRNS0519
union all Select * from TRNS0619 union all Select * from TRNS0719
```

my query is not taking `union all Select * from TRNS0819` because this isn't available in db

It should combine all  tables and show result in find temp table.
Please help

Comment: The best answer is: Fix your design. Why it's not one table with additional column to store `TRNS0719`... or even a `DATE` column?

Comment: first , you have to declare a Store procedure and put your query in that , 
then declare a job that occurs once a month and alter That Store procedure

Comment: do you have fixed dates when table gets generated and does it have mmyy at the end , write a stored procedure with dynamic sql?

Comment: The *real* answer is to fix the design. You won't need a UNION if you don't have multiple tables. Multiple tables don't improve performance, they only make deletes easier. If you need partitioning for data management purposes, use SQL Server's own partitions - they are available in all editions, including Express, since 20016 SP1. Before that they were an Enterprise feature.

Comment: If you insist on keeping multiple tables (why??) you *still* need the date column, with CHECK constraints that ensure it contains only values for that month. SQL Server's query optimizer will take them into account if you filter by date and only search the tables that would allow this date. BTW partitioning would do the same without the extra hassle

Comment: Finally, partitioning, whether manual or automatic, only makes sense if a table contains *millions of rows* and data movement is an issue. For fewer data, it's extra complexity that *doesn't* help in anything. It actually *harms* performance as the query engine will have to search more tables, more indexes. That's why the CHECK constraint is so important - it eliminates tables from the query

Comment: @user10991129 you can create a UNION ALL view and update it each month when you add the new table. That's far easier and more manageable than creating a dynamic query that tries to find and combine all the tables *every* time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the following code in stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @DynamicTSQLStatement = STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT N' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ' + '[' + SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]) + '].[' + [name] + ']'
        FROM [sys].[tables]
        WHERE [name] LIKE 'TRNS%'
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,10
    ,''
);

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;
```

You can add more filters when table name is extracted from the `[sys].[tables]` view.

Comment: I would use `'TRNS[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'` in case there is similar table names.

Comment: @Sami Sure. He can change the filtering criteria as he wish - for example extract tables only for certain schema.

Comment: A better option would be to create and update a VIEW with all the tables instead of creating a new query each time. This query can be used to generate and update the VIEW definition once a month, when the new table is added.

Comment: @gotqn Sir what is the meaning of this    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,10
    ,''
);

Comment: @user10991129 The select statement is building an XML - and with this clause we are extracting it as a string - `value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')`. Then with the `STUFF(..., 1, 10, '')` we are replacing the first `UNION ALL` value of this string. It is a common way to concatenate values in T-SQL in earlier versions.

Comment: Thankyou so much this is working perfectly in my scenario