# How to create a SQL procedure to union tables from a growing list of tables In SQLserver

Tags: sql-server

I need to consolidate information from multiple tables into a single table. The issue is new tables are being created and I have no control over when they are created or what they are called other than the beginning part of the name.

I would love it if this worked:

```
Select t.name
into #aReading
from sys.tables as t
where t.name like 'Fast_a%'

Select *
from (Select name from #aReading)
```

This works but constantly needs new tables added

```
Insert (col1, col2) into TestTable

Select x.* from (col1,col2
from test1

union

Select col1,col2
from test1_01022019

union
Select col1,col2
from test1_09122019 ) x
```

I am still learning SQL and not very good with `While` but thought that might be the answer.

Comment: Does the base table name stay the same, except for the date extensions?

Comment: You will need to do this with dynamic sql.   That said this is probably an XY problem, as a database that is constantly adding new tables with the same layout is probably not the best solution.

Comment: You want to use a query (string) from your app, a sql view, a stored procedure, a table-valued function?  From a stored procedure, it is possible to do want you want (but I'm not sure if my way is the best way).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perform Union if table with these names exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56965616/perform-union-if-table-with-these-names-exist)

Comment: Now would be a good time to discuss this situation with your team. Sounds like a process / implementation issue that might be better addressed by not creating what appear to be duplicate tables.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dynamic SQL example (e.g. build the query as a string and then use built in procedure sp_executesql to execute the query).

This example uses [STUFF and FOR XML PATH('')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server) to concatenate a bunch of queries together and stick ' UNION ' between each one.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO TestTable (col1, col2) '

SELECT @sql += STUFF(
    (SELECT ' UNION SELECT col1, col2 FROM ' + t.name
    FROM sys.tables as t
    WHERE t.name like 'Fast_a%'
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 7, '')

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

So, for this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE fast_a1 (col1 INT, col2 INT)
CREATE TABLE fast_a2 (col1 INT, col2 INT)
CREATE TABLE fast_aasdf (col1 INT, col2 INT)
CREATE TABLE TestTable (col1 INT, col2 INT)
```

It builds this dynamic query:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (col1, col2) 
SELECT col1, col2 FROM fast_a1 
UNION 
SELECT col1, col2 FROM fast_a2 
UNION 
SELECT col1, col2 FROM fast_aasdf
```

**Edit:**

Liz, run these statements ([or here's a SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/13549/1)) in sequence, and you'll see that they do insert data:

```
CREATE TABLE fast_a1 (col1 INT, col2 INT);
CREATE TABLE fast_a2 (col1 INT, col2 INT);
CREATE TABLE fast_aasdf (col1 INT, col2 INT);
CREATE TABLE TestTable (col1 INT, col2 INT);

INSERT INTO dbo.fast_a1 VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO dbo.fast_a2 VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO dbo.fast_aasdf VALUES (3, 3);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO TestTable (col1, col2) '

SELECT @sql += STUFF(
    (SELECT ' UNION SELECT col1, col2 FROM ' + t.name
    FROM sys.tables as t
    WHERE t.name like 'Fast_a%'
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 7, '')

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

SELECT * FROM dbo.TestTable
```

Returns:

```
col1    col2
1       1
2       2
3       3
```

Comment: @Liz, to help understand why this works, have a look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server

Comment: @EricBrandt Thanks for the link

Comment: Sure thing (he said, pretending he doesn't have to look it up, every. single. time.)

Comment: It doesn't error but it doesn't insert anything. The only changes I made were the real column names and not all the columns just a few.

Comment: @Liz see my edit. The posted script works; you may need to tweak your implementation. Good luck!